# Using join() inside a print statement for a list. is it possible?

Tags: python, for-loop, list-comprehension, human-readable

I am working on 4-11 in [Python Crash Course](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1593279280) for reference.
My task is to

> Print the message *My favorite pizzas are:,* and then use a for loop to print the list.

```py
fav_pizzas = ['pepperoni', 'pineapple', 'cheese']
friend_pizzas = fav_pizzas[:]

fav_pizzas.append('meat lovers')
friend_pizzas.append('veggie')

print(f"My favorite pizzas are: {fav_pizzas}")
print(f"My My friend's favorite pizzas are: {friend_pizzas}")
```

While I understand the concept of using list comprehension such as:

```py
odd_nums = [odd_num for odd_num in range(1, 21, 2)]
```

I am not sure how I would accomplish this with a list.
Deep down I know the most logical way would be to just create a new variable and do something like:

```py
space = " "
print(f"My favorite pizzas are, {space.join(fav_pizzas)}")
```

But the task is asking me to use a for loop.
If I am TOTALLY off the mark. Please do not hesitate to shame me, I am new to programming/coding and I expect it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need a variable, just put the space in the f-string.

```
print(f"My favorite pizzas are, {' '.join(fav_pizzas)}")
```

Comment: Oh wow! that's super helpful. Would I be able to do the same with a for loop?

Comment: No, you can only put expressions in f-strings, not statements.

Comment: But list comprehensions are expressions, so you can do that. But trying to put too much into a single statement makes confusing code, don't do that.